# ORA 12569 Packet checksum failure

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ssh

I am trying to connect to Oracle database on a remote server (on cloudapp) using an ssh key pair authentication method. I can connect to the server with this code.

```
        PrivateKeyFile keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(@"D:\ssh.ppk");
        var keyFiles = new[] { keyFile };
        var username = "Admin";

        var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();

        methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, keyFiles));

        var con = new ConnectionInfo("abc.xyz.net", 22, username, methods.ToArray());
        using (var client = new SshClient(con))
        {
            client.Connect();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
                client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
                portForwarded.Start();
                var connectionString = "DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=3306)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ABC_DB)));PASSWORD=myPassword;USER ID=myUsername";
                //var connectionString = "DATA SOURCE=127.0.0.1:3306/ABC_DB;PASSWORD=myPassword;USER ID=myUsername";
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    //conn.Open();
                    using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_Name", conn))
                    {

                        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(com);
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                client.Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client cannot be reached...");
            }
        }
```

When I try to connect to the database it throws an exception packet checksum failure at the line `da.Fill(ds);`. 
Can you please help me if you know what settings need to be changed, where.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> #### 12569, 00000, "TNS:packet checksum failure"
>
> **Cause:** The data received is not the same as the data sent.
>
> **Action:** Attempt the transaction again. If the error is persistent, turn on tracing and reexecute the operation.

There must be mismatch on the tcp packet between server and client. You have to enable tracing on both sites, server and client.

Contact Network Administrators to fix packet problem on the basis of trace information.

**References:**

[Tracing Error Information for Oracle Net Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm#i468763)

**Getting ORA-12569: TNS:Packet Checksum Failure While Trying To Connect Through Client. (Doc ID 257793.1)**

Comment: How do you enable tracing on server and client? I am on windows.